# Responsiveness on random dynamic divs

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a little problem. I have a dynamic page that will be filled with divs.
The number of divs vary on the content registered at the database.

I need to make a horizontal responvive layout.
Each div will have a min-width, however whenever they breakdown, they will all have the same width.

If needed, I do have bootstrap, jquery and angular to play with.

I hope the pictures can explain better:

[image: Layout with 2 divs]

[image: Layout with 3 divs]

[image: Layout with 7 divs]

Comment: You could just swap the `ng-class` using bootstrap classes depending on what you get in. Have a function that returns a col-md-x where x is determined by the amount of results you get in.

Comment: Or you can do the same thing with jquery and bootstrap -- you should should how your code is set up. Is this an app or a webpage, or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is more or less what @ajmajmajma proposed...

http://plnkr.co/edit/dgDPzC4wdKihS73b4d0h?p=preview

The html is pretty simple:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-repeat="city in theCities" class="myInfo {{myClass}}">
    {{city.info}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In the controller just set $scope.myClass depending on how many items are in theCities.

Reduce the number of items in theCities array to see how the output responds.  There is likely a cleaner way to set up the class, this plunker just tries to get the idea across.

Comment: This is interesting sir.
I thought some javascript code would be needed for the dynamism.
I did add the min-width:200px to limit a size and it worked as intended. 
Is it wrong to do so??

Comment: Not necessarily wrong, no.... but I think the bootstrap method will be a little more consistent.  It has the added benefit of changing it for mobiles, etc.  Something like class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4", something like that.  So on a small device you would get 2 columns instead of 3.

Answer (score -1):

You can use table cells. This might sound old school, but I feel this will be efficient and reliable to this particular requirement.